# How to change gcp project billing to different billing organization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My company is willing to pay for my personal GCP projects and want me to change the billing id for my projects?
How do I achieve this?
Does my personal email have to be added to their billing org? OR can I just change billing id for my project?

Comment: I suspect only someone that is both a Billing Account Administrator on your company's billing account and at the same time Project Billing Manager on your project can do that. You can probably add a company admin as Project Billing Manager and allow them to attach the project.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to have them (probably!) assign your project to the organizational billing account; they own the billing account resource and only identities permitted to use it can apply it.

> **NOTE** If your identity has the appropriate IAM role for your organization's billing account then, you could also make the change but I suspect (you asked this question that) it doesn't (and you probably shouldn't anyway) do this.

In order to do this, they will need (I think) `roles/billing.projectManager` on your (!) project.

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access

The change will only happen proactively (for charges incurred after the change of billing account is effective)

Comment: Do I need to migrate my project from my personal account to theirs?

Comment: @justrying - No, you do not need to migrate your project. You can add any project to a billing account with the correct IAM permissions. Someone will need **Project Billing Manager** on the project and **Billing Account User** or better on the billing account. Ask the company for the IAM user email address of their billing account user and add that identity to your project with the Project Billing Manager role.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do so. As long as the Billing Account owner (or operator) is willing to accept (and it's their action) billing from your project, it *should* work for any project regardless. It's possible that there are organizational policies that may prohibit this. I don't know. It's possible that they can't add project owners who aren't on their domain, for example. But, in that case, you should be able to add yourself (or other) using an organizational identify as a project member.

Comment: @justrying I also recommend that you begin labeling your project resources. Enable billing export to BigQuery. The billing account user can then generate reports on billing data.